# Problem with connection between Flask Celery and RabbitMQ in docker containers

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery

I have a problem with connection between Flask+Celery+ngnx+gunicorn to broker in another container.
starting a celery in flask app container:

```
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:41:50,278: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:41:50,278: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:41:50,278: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:41:50,864: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:41:50,865: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:41:50,865: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection    
smsc    | [2021-03-15 22:27:17,637: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@185.xx.xxx.xx:5673/mainhost: timed out.
    Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

The problem is weird: RabbitMQ is on VPS as docker container. Flask is in one container, nginx second.
When I'm running flask app outside container on developer mode it works fine. When I'm running docerized flask+nignx LOCALY (but broker is always on VPS) it works fine. Then I'm sending my app on VPS, run and... error. Any ideas what's wrong?

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  smsc:
    container_name: smsc
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/SMSC/logs:/app/logs
      - ~/SMSC/excel:/app/excel
    build:
      context: ./flask_app
    ports:
      - "8005:8000"

  smsc-nginx:
    container_name: smsc-nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "85:80"
    depends_on:
      - smsc
```

I was thinking that it was docker network problem but i use `docker network connect bridge <CONTAINER>`, and few oder commands, and it still not working. Why app container can't se broker by global IP ?
I have another app on vps with similar setup and it's working with this broker. Why this not?

celery setup from my `__init__` app file:

```
class Config:
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:pass@185.xx.xxx.xx:5673/mainhost'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+postgresql://user:pass@185.xx.xxx.xx:5432/tasks'
    CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT = True

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL,
        backend=Config.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = Flask(__name__)
celery = make_celery(app)
```

Comment: Please show the celery app config in your flask app - at least the broker settings

Comment: You named your container manually. Are you sure those names are unique ?

Comment: @im_baby I've added celery and flask init configs to main post. But as i said - it must be a docker/ip problem, because it is working on desktop, and not working on machine with rabbitmq. I've tried with local container IPs in CELERY_BROKER_URL - but still nothing.  
run command for rabbitmq:
`docker run --hostname rabbitmq --name rabbitmq0 -p 5673:5672 -p 8088:15672 -v /rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3-management`
and manually added to bridge network and default network automatically created by docker-compose

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux yes, I'm using a script. It is deleting containers with this names

Comment: IMO you shouldn't worry about extra configuration for the docker network. You are already binding ports to the host machine so your services will be available via localhost on those ports.

Comment: @im_baby I thought so too, but changing broker url to localhost, 0.0.0.0, rabbitmq0 doesn't work either... 
i've checked connection with postgress and this flask app (CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND) and it is working perfectly fine. Postgres is situated in container on VPS, exactly as rabbitmq. So it must be a rabbitmq problem...